# IPTables will not listen to rules

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall

Before you answer, I have tried UFW and GUFW plus multiple others and they did not work either. I am only using IPTables as an general name due to the fact it is the one I really want.

I've set everything to DROP and then added the ports I want to work (say https and http for web browsing) then I have saved my rule set (even rebooted afterwards on the second try) and it won't load anything (firefox, chrome/ium, opera (plus apps like pidgin on their ports), it will look like it is loading but after 10 minutes it will give up. I've tried everything, check if it is going in the right direction (in/out) even enabled both but nothing. Nada.

I think it could be a wireless driver/network card issue (I'm on a Mac laptop, ergh). I could be wrong though, hence why I asked here. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Iptables -L log (not copied and pasted ~ manually typed up due to on another device):

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target    prot opt source        destination
ACCEPT    tcp -- anywhere        anywhere        tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT    tcp -- anywhere        anywhere        tcp dpt:https

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target    prot opt source        destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target    prot opt source        destination
ACCEPT    tcp -- anywhere        anywhere        tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT    tcp -- anywhere        anywhere        tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT    udp -- anywhere        anywhere        udp dpt:http
ACCEPT    udp -- anywhere        anywhere        udp dpt:https
```

Comment: Can you put output from command `iptables -L` in you question?

Comment: @2707974 I will, just give me a bit.

Comment: @2707974 Added IPtables -L log to question.

Comment: I'm no iptables expert, but don't you need to allow DNS as well before http(s) can even work?

Comment: @potAito Just tried allowing DNS on port 53 and still got nothing.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how connections **from** the web work: unless you're running a webserver **on** the machine, you don't need to allow incoming to `dpt:http`, instead you need to allow packets that are established by / related to your outgoing web connections.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start

On some `pc` you have web server and you wish to deny any except input to port `80` and `443`

Delete curent rules and chains

```
sudo iptables --flush
sudo iptables --delete-chain
```

allow loopback

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

allow established connections

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

allow `80` and `443`

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

default policies

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

In case to allow access from `pc` only to `80` and `443` do 
Delete curent rules and chains

```
sudo iptables --flush
sudo iptables --delete-chain
```

allow loopback

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

allow established connections

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

allow traffic to `80` and `443`

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

default policies

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

This is it. I think :)

Comment: Still not working, I'm trying to deny everything except for rules I allow (like 80 and 443).

Comment: I think he is not working on a server, but wants to configure a client. He basically wants a client where only http(s) connections are permitted.

Comment: @potAito Yeah, sorry should of added that. Also what ever pidgin (or jabber and irc) plus anything else I need (which I could find the right port number in with the same command as 80 and 443?

Comment: You can use same command for OUTPUT rules only change port.

Comment: @2707974 I tried that and still got nowhere. Nothing loads. Could it be a wireless driver issue, should I buy a more Linux compatible wireless card?

Comment: Also notice the rules are not saving no matter what I try. What the f*** is happening? I think I am going gray with all the stress this is causing me, haha.

Comment: If you can ping `8.8.8.8` maybe you have problem with dns. Try by adding following `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT